# Override mkdir in bash / shell

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal, alias

for more comfort I like to override mkdir like this:

```
mkdir() {
  if [[ "$@" == *--parents* ]]; then
    builtin mkdir "$@"
  else
    builtin mkdir "$@" --parents
  fi
}
```

Unfortunately there is no builtin of mkdir. How can I do a workaround that does the job?

Comment: It seems like you want to call `mkdir` always with the --parents option, why not just alias it like this: `alias mkdir='mkdir -p'`

Comment: That's nice! I would love to vote this as the best answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `command` built-in instead:

```
mkdir() {
  if [[ "$@" == *--parents* ]]; then
    command mkdir "$@"
  else
    command mkdir "$@" --parents
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir_p=`which mkdir`
```

after that you can call it with:

```
$mkdir_p args...
```

or

```
alias mkdir=¨mkdir -p¨
```